# Regex python ignore word followed by given character

Tags: python, regex

I have the regex `(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]))@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)(?!\w)`.

Given the string `@first@nope @second@Hello @my-friend, email@ whats.up@example.com @friend`, what can I do to exclude the strings `@first` and `@second` since they are not whole words on their own ?
In other words, exclude them since they are succeeded by **@** .

Comment: Yes. I want to get `['my-friend', 'friend']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
(?<![a-zA-Z0-9_.-])@(?=([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_-]*))\1(?![@\w])
(?a)(?<![\w.-])@(?=([A-Za-z][\w-]*))\1(?![@\w])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KFHwo8/3). *Details*:

- `(?<![a-zA-Z0-9_.-])` - a negative lookbehind that matches a location that is not immediately preceded with ASCII digits, letters, `_`, `.` and `-`
- `@` - a `@` char
- `(?=([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_-]*))` - a positive lookahead with a capturing group inside that captures one or more ASCII letters and then zero or more ASCII letters, digits, `-` or `_` chars
- `\1` - the Group 1 value (backreferences are atomic, no backtracking is allowed through them)
- `(?![@\w])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a word char (letter, digit or `_`) or a `@` char immediately to the right of the current location.

Note I put hyphens at the end of the character classes, this is best practice.

The `(?a)(?<![\w.-])@(?=([A-Za-z][\w-]*))\1(?![@\w])` alternative uses shorthand character classes and the `(?a)` inline modifier (equivalent of `re.ASCII` / `re.A` makes `\w` only match ASCII chars (as in the original version). Remove `(?a)` if you plan to match any Unicode digits/letters.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you explain how it differs from mine ?

Comment: @ImportError Two main differences: 1) the final lookahead fails if there is a `@` on the right, 2) the main part is made *atomic* so that the final lookahead was triggered only once, and if it fails, it cannot cause backtracking into the main pattern part. The first lookbehind thing is just an enhancement.

Comment: I guess `(?<![\w.-])@(?=([A-Za-z]+[\w-]*))\1(?![@\w])` would also work?

Comment: @rv.kvetch I updated the answer.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Just wanted to explain why atomic approach is used: in a `@my-friend-@friend` string, no match should be found as the `-` is part of the word you want to extract, and if you remove the atomic equivalent, and use `(?<![\w.-])@([A-Za-z][\w-]*)(?![@\w])`, you [will get](https://regex101.com/r/KFHwo8/5) `@my-friend` as a match.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to assert a whitespace boundary to the left, and assert no word char or @ sign to the right.

```
(?<!\S)@([A-Za-z]+[\w-]+)(?![@\w])
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind, assert not a non whitespace char to the left
- `@` Match literally
- `([A-Za-z]+[\w-]+)` Capture group1, match 1+ chars A-Za-z and then 1+ word chars or `-`
- `(?![@\w])` Negative lookahead, assert not @ or word char to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v2OGdL/1)

Or match a non word boundary `\B` before the @ instead of a lookbehind.

```
\B@([A-Za-z]+[\w-]+)(?![@\w])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GRV8x4/1)